# Is there a way to fast copy files from old ftp server to another ftp server?

Tags: ftp

Moving to a new host I need to copy big files and my upload speed is slow to do that from my PC. How can I copy from old ftp server (PHP) to new one directly ?

Comment: what sort of access do you have on the old and new hosts? Would compressing first be an option?

Comment: the old host is very slow and I try compressing it get canceled from cp file manager this is why I am moving

Comment: Edited to remove asking for software (which is off topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two FTP servers support the
[File eXchange Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_eXchange_Protocol),
you may do this using an FTP client that supports it.

An example is
[FTP Rush](https://www.wftpserver.com/ftprush.htm),
a free program for Windows that is available as a portable version and setup version.

For a review, see the article
[Transfer files directly between servers with FTP Rush](https://www.ghacks.net/2014/12/11/transfer-files-directly-between-servers-with-ftp-rush/).

[image]

If one of the servers does not support this protocol, you could possibly use
a cloud service such as
[MultCloud](https://www.multcloud.com/tutorials/direct-ftp-to-ftp-transfer-1004.html),
where the free account lets you copy up to 50 GB of data.

Comment: While true, FXP is actually very rarely supported.

Comment: Thanks I am trying multcloud but is there any indication that the transfer is working ? I dont see any progress

Comment: See if something is arriving on the FTP server.

Comment: yes this is great, I tried to google for something like this for 3 days but did not found any....thanks alot